How to use amazon rekognition to track people by their name
Currently, I am doing a project in which I need to process the video inputs from two CCTV feeds; one is located outside the ATM gate (CCTV-1) and the other one is located in the inside the ATM (CCTV-2). I was provided with the following requirements and constraints:
First, I was told that I know the name of the person that is going to enter inside the ATM and I have to use Amazon Rekognition in order to identify that person.
Second, I have to track that person from CCTV-1 to CCTV-2; for example, the same ID and name should be there in both the feeds in order to determine that this is the same person. And the challenges that I have is that not all the times the person's face would be entirely visible. It sometimes may be a frontal view, sometimes a side profile and mostly a back profile.
Some of my questions are: with the Amazon Rekognition, is there a single service or APIs I can use that would provide me with a service that allows identification as well as the ability to continue tracking a single person across multiple feeds of multiple CCTVs? Or, a question on the constraints, is there a workaround or some other AWS service I would need to use instead if this is not a civilized service?
Ultimately, I am seeking answers about the most optimal way to do this, including any new AWS services, architecture recommendations and best practices.

You can 'teach' Amazon Rekognition the name of a face when you store a face in a Face Collection. You do this by providing an ExternalImageId when calling IndexFaces(). That ID will be stored with the face when it is added to a Face Collection.
See: Adding faces to a collection - Amazon Rekognition
Later, when asking Rekognition to SearchFacesByImage() in an image you provide, Rekognition will provide the ExternalImageId for any faces it recognizes from the Face Collection.
Therefore, you could use a person's name as the ExternalImageId and it will tell you whenever an image contains that person. Note that the system first needs to be 'trained' by providing their face and ID to initially store in the Face Collection.
Processing video is much more difficult (and costly). You would stream the video to Amazon Kinesis Video Streams, which can then use Amazon Rekognition Video to detect faces in the video stream.
See:

Working with streaming video events - Amazon Rekognition
Setting up your Amazon Rekognition Video and Amazon Kinesis resources - Amazon Rekognition

